# To estimate a Markov random field, do we have to assume a DAG generated the data?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, networks, partial-correlation, dag, markov-random-field

Even if I believe that I understood the Markov Random Fields and DAGs separately, I encountered a question that I have written in the title and cannot come up with a clear-cut answer. Can you help me out?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what make you think so ? It is hard to understand what you mean. Except if you have hidden Markov fields in mind, where the observed random variables can, in the classical model, be represented as generated from the hidden random variables with arrows. (in this case the global model is a mix of directed/undirected graphical model)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. We just learned DAGs and undirected models (MRF and Ising model) in the class. In my assignment, there are true/false questions just like the one that I have written in the title. Do we need to assume that only a DAG structure can create Markov random fields? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe there is something I don't get but that looks so strange to me because by definition MRF are undirected graphical models opposed to directed graphical models (among which you find the DAG)...